# How to send an email from an Excel Add-in (js)

Tags: office-js

I'm trying to convert a VBA macro I use extensively to JS/HTML.   It takes the current selected range, checks if the contents look like email addresses, and then composes an email to those people.

I've got the framework working, but can't find out how to send an email from my Excel addin.   I can't seem to access the Outlook api (office.mailbox) from an Excel host.

Using mailto works but has a size limit which isn't sufficient because I'm specifying long bodies and possibly hundreds of recipients.

```
window.location.href = "mailto:user@example.com
```

In VBA the macro looks like this:

```
Sub EmailSelected()
    Dim OutlookApp As Object
    Dim Mess As Object, Recip As String
    Dim selRange As Range
    ' If there is only one cell selected, don't call SpecialCells, it messes up
    If selection.Count = 1 Then
        Set selRange = selection
    Else
        Set selRange = selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    End If

    ' If the first cell contains an email address, send as email.
    If InStr(selRange.Item(1).Value, "@") > 0 Then
        For Each c In selRange.Cells
            Recip = Recip & c.Value & ";"
        Next
        Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set Mess = OutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
        If selRange.Count = 1 Then
            Mess.To = Recip
        Else
            Mess.BCC = Recip
        End If

        Mess.Display
    Else
        ' google the cell contents
        For Each c In selRange.Cells
            Recip = Recip & c.Value & " "
        Next
        ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink ("http://www.google.ca/search?q=" & Recip)
    End If
End Sub
```

Another option would be calling the macro from my excel add-in (suboptimal but could work).  However I can't find a way to do this either.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mailto is ideal, but if there's too much data then you could use the Outlook REST APIs via Microsoft Graph instead. Here's documentation on the APIs for sending mail: https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/message_send. The advantage here is you have much finer control over the entire process, including the actual Send operation (not just creating new messages). The main disadvantage is that you'll have more code to write with this approach.

Comment: Thanks.  I will look into the graph api.  Looks like there is no other way around this.   I do find it a bit odd that you can't access Outlook APIs from other hosts.   Office being a unified product you would think this would be useful in all sorts of different cases